# How to tackle with the precision of the result from the String to sum(numbers)

Tags: python-3.x

```
def strint2():
total=0
t=0
for i in "1.23,2.4,3.123":
    if(i.isdigit()):
        x=int(i)
    if(i!='.' and i!=','):
        x=x/(10**t)
        t=t+1
        total=total+x
    if(i==","):
        t=0         
print(total)
```

The result is `6.752999999999999` instead of `6.753` (the sum of numbers in the string)
I want to make this program with nameless String { without doing this s=""} 
please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Any fix for this, in python 3?